# Split strings by a certain delimiter and extract the output for further processing

Tags: bash, split

I have a list of directory names (each in one line) that consist of the names of rubygems and their version.

I want to split them at the last hyphen in the string.

The folder-name string consists

- of the name of the gem
- and as the second part of a version number

How can one extract both for further processing and keep a relationship between the gem-name and the version-numbers established?

Given the list that `find` returns

```
find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "^./[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*-[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,3}){,3}\$"
```

My approach would have been nested arrays, like this

```
declare -A my_gems
my_gems[gem_name]=()
# append version numbers to the right hand side array
```

I need to further process it in the context of parsing user arguments to a script which contains of a gem_name and a list of versions.

Comment: `find ... | while IFS=- read -ra name version; do my_gems["$name"]="$version"; done`

Comment: But I thought that it's not possible to assign an array `$version` to a Hash `$my_gems` ?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're asking. The `IFS` split the `folder-version` into name and version.

Comment: I mean that I thought `declare -A my_gems=()` wasn't possible. I.e. having a normal array as value of an associative array. Best wishes !

Comment: Ok with process substitution `< <(find ...)`

Comment: Seems to work, only one small part left. The output of find is with a trailing `./` each line. I know I could substitute it via `sed 's/.\{2\}//` away. If there is no more apt way to do this.. Where would I place such a command to remove the trailing `./` from the `find` output ?

Comment: `"${line#*./}"`

Comment: Which is where? I'm sorry. Tried to nest the parameter expansions but this is also not valid obviously.

Comment: The solution is almost perfect. But the place is already taken by "${line#-*}". Excuse me. Best wishes

Comment: Adjusted the answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `while` `read` loop approach should be something like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A my_gems
find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "^./[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*-[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,3}){,3}\$" | {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    line=${line#*./}
    my_gems[${line%-*}]=${line##*-}
  done
}

declare -p my_gems
```

---

As suggested by @oguz using a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A my_gems

while IFS= read -r line; do
  line=${line#*./}
  my_gems[${line%-*}]=${line##*-}
done < <(find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "^./[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*-[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,3}){,3}\$")

declare -p my_gems
```

Comment: Looks like this should work. Is a slight modification possible? How does the split occur at the last hyphen ("-") in the filename ?

Comment: @von It occurs at the **first** hyphen.

Comment: Any chance to let it occur at the last hyphen? :)

Comment: Well, you can add another variable. `first` `name` `version` ?

Comment: @oguzismail I have seen this idiom before but I don't get the `<(find ...)` part to work

Comment: @vonspotz Yea there was a typo there, it should be `done < <(` not `done <(`.

Comment: A BIG "thank you" both guys for your efforts! I'm still learning and it's nice to see people on SO who don't look down on newbs. Best wishes!